# PHP: Convert single-quoted string into double-quoted

Tags: php, unicode, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

I need to convert string with unicode \xCODEs into regular string. 
The issue is that string which I have as input seems to be single-quoted.

Is there any way to convert single-quoted string into double?

*Here's some code for better understanding:*

```
$s1 = '(single quotes): Conductivity @ 20\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0C';
$s2 = "(double quotes): Conductivity @ 20\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0C";

echo "<br>";
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $s1);
echo "<br>";
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $s2);
```

will output:

```
(single quotes): Conductivity @ 20\xc3\x82\xc2\xb0C
(double quotes): Conductivity @ 20°C
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just double quote it when you define it in the first place - you can read about the differences [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Else see [`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/stripcslashes).

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not defining it, I have it as input.

Comment: @mario it seems to be what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns that I was looking for [stripcslashes](http://php.net/stripcslashes)

Many thanks @mario!