# Sending an email via PHP with the body in MYSQL db and parsing \n

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email via PHP and the body of the email is stored in a MYSQL database. For some reason when I hardcode the body as a string, it converts characters like "\n" to a paragraph break, but when it's extracted from the MYSQL database, it leaves "\n" in. Anyone have a good idea why that is and how to fix it? I've tried converting it into a string, but to no avail.

the code:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Tickets LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($ticket = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $ticket_queue_id = $ticket["ticket_queue_id"];
        $subject = "test";
        $body = $ticket["body"];
        $headers = "From: Email";
        mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers);
        echo "Sent test";
    }
```

"Tickets" is a MYSQL table, where $ticket["body"] is stored as a varchar.

In the email, the above code gives something like "Hello\n\world" in the body,

While

```
        $subject = "test";
        $body = $ticket["body"];
        $headers = "From: Email";
        mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

looks like:

"Hello

world"

Thanks!

Comment: Replace it with whitespace?

Comment: I need it to be a paragraph break! Whitespace shows up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Have to encapsulate $ticket["body"] with stripcslashes. Found from here: [PHP: Convert single-quoted string into double-quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444753/php-convert-single-quoted-string-into-double-quoted)